# How do I overcome the "VerifyError:Expecting a stackmap frame" for a JDK 7/8 application?

Tags: java, jvm, java-bytecode-asm

I am using ASM 5.0.3 bytecode modification library with Tomcat 8 and JDK 8.

My intention is to inject bytecode successfully into all the classes. However, I encountered the following error:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 18
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/sun/crypto/provider/SunJCE.getInstance()Lcom/sun/crypto/provider/SunJCE; @0: getstatic
  Reason:
    Expected stackmap frame at this location.
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: b200 0bc7 000b bb00 3659 b700 0cb0 b200
    0x0000010: 0bb0 bf                                
  Exception Handler Table:
    bci [0, 18] => handler: 18
  Stackmap Table:
    append_frame(@14,Integer)

            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$2.run(Unknown Source)
            at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$2.run(Unknown Source)
           ......Some more uninteresting lines in the stack trace.......
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)
```

The key parts of the code that I used in order to call ASM's methods are as follows:

```
ClassWriter classWriter = new  ClassWriter(classReader, ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS);

classReader.accept(myClassVisitor, ClassReader.EXPAND_FRAMES);
```

The above code works perfectly well with bytecode modification of a JDK 6 application. The error shows up only for JDK 7 and JDK 8 applications.

Various blog posts and stackoverflow posts point to using the -XX:-UseSplitVerifier or the -noverify  flags. However this seems like a short-term workaround especially given that the -XX:-UseSplitVerifier flag is deprecated in JDK 8. I would like to achieve a permanent solution rather than rely on a flag that would eventually be unsupported in future Java releases.

Thank you in advance.

*Edit:*  In reference to Adam's kind suggestion of using `COMPUTE_FRAMES` instead of `COMPUTE_MAXS`, this link [ASM - java.lang.VerifyError: Operand stack overflow Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495462/asm-java-lang-verifyerror-operand-stack-overflow-exception) summarizes the errors so far with `COMPUTE_FRAMES`. Currently, I am unable to progress on JDK 7/8 with either of `COMPUTE_MAXS` or `COMPUTE_FRAMES`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue, after extending ClassWriter class and override the method getCommonSuperClass.

Please check this [ASM 5.0.3 With Java 1.8 incorrect maxStack with Java.lang.VerifyError: Operand stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35145997/asm-5-0-3-with-java-1-8-incorrect-maxstack-with-java-lang-verifyerror-operand-s?noredirect=1#comment58021378_35145997)

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`ClassWriter#COMPUTE_FRAMES`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassWriter.html#COMPUTE_FRAMES) flag for the stack map frames to be recomputed. The bytecode verifier uses typechecker (stack map) [from JDK 7 on](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6693236), so that's why your code works on JDK 6.

Note that (from `COMPUTE_FRAMES` JavaDoc):

> computeFrames implies computeMaxs

Comment: Hi Adam, Should I use ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES **instead of** ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS? Or is the ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES **in addition to** invoking ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS?

Comment: Yes, use `COMPUTE_FRAMES` instead of just `COMPUTE_MAXS`.

Comment: Hi Adam: Thanks for your follow up so far. This link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495462/asm-java-lang-verifyerror-operand-stack-overflow-exception summarizes the (erroneous) results so far with `COMPUTE_FRAMES`.